# How to split string that is a mathematical expression into separate parts (including operators)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to separate the digits from characters and letters and add them to a list.

```
n = "1+22-3*4/5"
eq=list(n)
c=0
for i in eq:
  if "*" in eq:
    while "*" in eq:
      c=eq.index("*")
      eq[c-1]=float(eq[c-1])*float(eq[c+1])
      del eq[c]
      del eq[c]
      print(eq)
  if "/" in eq:
    while "/" in eq:
      c=eq.index("/")
      eq[c-1]=float(eq[c-1])/float(eq[c+1])
      del eq[c]
      del eq[c]
      print(eq)
  if "+" in eq:
    while "+" in eq:
      c=eq.index("+")
      eq[c-1]=float(eq[c-1])+float(eq[c+1])
      del eq[c]
      del eq[c]
      print(eq)
  if "-" in eq:
    while "-" in eq:
      c=eq.index("-")
      eq[c-1]=float(eq[c-1])-float(eq[c+1])
      del eq[c]
      del eq[c]
  print(eq)
print(n,"=",eq)
```

It can only append every digit in the list.
The current output is ['1','+','2','2','-','3','*','4','/','5']

Comment: This is confusing. The output is ` ['1','+','2','2','-','3','*','4','/','5']` but the expected output is?

Comment: ['1','+','22','-','3','*','4','/','5'] sir

Comment: Why don't you just use `sympy`?

Comment: This seems to be an ideal situation for a regex.  http://regex101.com

Comment: If the regex solution was the most helpful for your problem, you should mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you process the characters of the string in order (for ch in str) and either (a) add them to your list; or (b) accumulate them into a number:

```
str = "1+22-3*4/5"
tokens = []
number = None
operators = "+-*/"
digits = "0123456789"

for ch in str:
    if ch in operators:
        if number is not None:
            tokens.append(number)
        tokens.append(ch)
        continue
    elif ch in digits:
        if number is None:
            number = ch
        else:
            number += ch
        continue
    else:
        # what else could it be?
        pass

# After loop, check for number at end 
if number is not None:
   tokens.append(number)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with `str.isdigit` as the key function:

```
from itertools import groupby
[''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(n, key=str.isdigit)]
```

This returns:

```
['1', '+', '22', '-', '3', '*', '4', '/', '5']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re
s = "1+22-3*4/5"
re.split('(\W)', s)
```

#### Output

```
['1', '+', '22', '-', '3', '*', '4', '/', '5']
```

Comment: Note that this will return an empty string as the first item if the first token is not a number/word. For example, if `s = "-1+22-3*4/5"`, this will output `['', '-', '1', '+', '22', '-', '3', '*', '4', '/', '5']`.

Answer (score 1):

Some great solutions here using `stdlib`, here's a pure python try:

```
i = "11+11*11"

def parser(i):
  out = []
  gram = []
  for x in i:
    if x.isdigit():
      gram.append(x)
    else:
      out.append("".join(gram))
      out.append(x)
      gram = []
  if gram:
    out.append("".join(gram))
  return out

parser(i) # ['11', '+', '11', '*', '11']
```